# Styled Components - content passed through props (content)

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to toggle text inside a div (styled component) depending on the props value. The idea is simple: state changes, its value goes to props of the styled component, and then depending what it is, the content adjusts. What is not working is the content in before / after. Any idea why?

STYLED COMPONENT:

```
export const Info = styled.div`
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  &::after {
 content: ${props => props.content === "intro" && "hello"};
  }
`
```

JS

```
const CheckNumber = () => {

  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("intro")

  return (

        <Info content={msg}/>
  )
}

export default CheckNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code generates style

```
content: hello
```

that is invalid CSS. You need extra quotes(one pair for JS level and nested quotes for CSS):

```
  &::after {
     content: ${props => props.content === "intro" && "'hello'"};
  }
```

PS found that really accidentally by duplicating `content` like:

```
  &::after {
     content: "aaaa";
     content: ${props => props.content === "intro" && "hello"};
  }
```

because browser just did not create "::after" prseudoelement while `content` is invalid - so we were unable to check what styles were actually generated.